# battery receiver does not keep variable

Tags: android

I have a int variable witch holds the old battery value it is declared in the top of the class. The problem is that the variable is not keeping it's value. I have tried static, volatile keywords but none of them worked.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `BroadcastReceiver` registered in the manifest via a `<receiver>` element will live long enough for a single `onReceive()` call. Any data that it needs to keep should be stored in a file (e.g., database).

A `BroadcastReceiver` registered via `registerReceiver()` from an `Activity` or `Service` has a lifetime dictated by that `Activity` or `Service`. Any data that should remain after the `Activity` or `Service` is destroyed should be stored in a file (e.g., database).